# merge/Condense list based on condition

Tags: python, list

Below example list -

```
a = [[0, 1], [3, 4], [5, 11], [12, 17], [20, 25], [26, 28]]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[[0,1], [3,17], [20,8]]
```

**Logic**

If we compare each element pairwise, if the difference of the last element of `i-1` and first element of `i` is < 2, then condense the list to just represent the lower bound of the `i-1` element and the upper bound of `i`.

This continues as covered in the example - element 2, 3 and 4 get merged from `[3, 4], [5, 11], [12, 17]` to just `[3,17]`.

**What I have tried**

```
a = [[0, 1], [3, 4], [5, 11], [12, 17], [20, 25], [26, 28]]
b = []
lower_curr = a[0][0]
upper_curr = a[0][1]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    lower_1 = a[i][0]
    lower_2 = a[i+1][1]

    upper_1 = a[i][1]
    upper_2 = a[i+1][1]

    if upper_1 - lower_2 >= 2:
        b.append((lower_1, upper_1))
    else:
        lower_curr = lower_1
        upper_curr = upper_2
```

What I am unable to do is to write logic on when to append either `lower_1` vs `lower_curr`. Feel free to write your own logic or fix mine.

Comment: Are the numbers always in ascending order or do we need to sort them as well?

Comment: always in ascending

Comment: Can we also use other packages or do you want it to be solved in pure python?

Comment: I guess other packages are ok as long as it's not very heavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider using a generator for this

```
from copy import copy
def condense(lst):
    current = copy(lst[0])
    for i, j in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
        if j[0] - i[1] > 1:
            yield copy(current)
            current = j
        else:
            current[1] = j[-1]
    yield copy(current)

a = [[0, 1], [3, 4], [5, 11], [12, 17], [20, 25], [26, 28]]
list(condense(a))
```

gives

```
[[0, 1], [3, 17], [20, 28]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be the brute-force approach to the solution.
In my approach, I have initialized the variables along with a changes variable. I have made changes to a copy of the list.
The algorithm is as follows:

1. Cycle through the list from indexes `0` to `len(a)-1` in order to prevent array index out of bounds error.
2. At each step check whether the difference between the last element at the current index and 1st element of the next index is less than 2
3. If yes, the changes are made to the copy of the list. The changes include setting the last element of the current index to the last element of the next index and popping out the next index.
4. The `changes` variable is used to update the index value such that it brings the changes to the next element each time.

The Code:

```
a = [[0, 1], [5, 6], [7, 11], [11, 21], [27, 29], [30, 38], [39, 41], [43, 50], [52, 52], [55, 56]] #The main list
b = a[:]
changes = 0
i = 0
while i < len(a)-1:
    if a[i+1][0] - a[i][1] < 2:
        b[i-changes][1] = b[i-changes+1][1] # Change the 2nd elemnent of the 
                                            # element at the current index.
        b = b[:i+1-changes] + b[i+2-changes:] # Removing the next element(I prefer 
                                              # it this way)
        changes += 1 # Updating the changes value every time an element is popped
    i+= 1
print(b)
```

Comment: @AhmedAEK it is a while statement so no that wouldn't work, it would cause an infinite loop if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: okay, i get your code now, the `changes` part is a little confusing, as you have `i` moving forward and `changes` moving backwards.

Answer (score 0):

just edit your code slightly, you don't need to track that much of variables, only the current lower limit, that is updated whenever you append to the list, and the upper bound that is always updated, because this will increase on each iteration.

and you just have to append whenever the condition is violated, and also append the last result, because the last element cannot violate any condition.

```py
a = [[0, 1], [3, 4], [5, 11], [12, 17], [20, 25], [26, 28]]
b = []
lower_curr = a[0][0]
upper_curr = a[0][1]
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    lower_2 = a[i][0]
    upper_2 = a[i][1]

    if lower_2 - upper_curr >= 2:
        b.append([lower_curr,upper_curr])
        lower_curr = lower_2
    upper_curr = upper_2
    
b.append([lower_curr,upper_curr])
print(b)
```